# Perl arrange array of dates chronologically

Tags: perl

I have an array `@dates` like this:

```
month [
    [0]  "Sep 8, 12, 15, 24",
    [1]  "May 3, 24, 25, 29",
    [2]  "Jan 23",
    ...
]
```

*Where each month will only be included in the array @month once, but not in chronological order.*

Does perl have a built in function to attempt to interpret a string as a date that I could use to sort this array chronologically?

Comment: No, no builtin like that. There are a number of good modules, and you can create objects out of each date specification and then use module's functionality to sort. What you show can be parsed by hand pretty easily, too.

Comment: @zdim I'm considering making an array with all month shorts `["jan", "feb", ...]` then doing something like: `foreach (@shorts) { foreach (@month) #pop from @month to @month_sorted if first word == $short`

Comment: And then you would want to sort asciibetical for the name, but numerical for the first day, because `Sep 25` needs to be later than `Sep 8`, which `"Sep 25" cmp "Sep 8"` will get wrong.

Comment: @simbabque I'm trying to say I don't need to order days. I just need to order strings which contain a month and list of days. So for `"Sep 8, 12, 15, 24"` I don't need to worry about the days I just need to make sure it comes after `"Jan 23"` in the array.

Comment: Ah, that's easier.  (It is a very specific restriction though. A tricky design decision to make, to rely on it.)  Then yes, you only need the first three chars.  Still need to pull them out though.  And you'll need some ancillary data structure, because how does the comparison routine know that `jan` comes before `feb`?

Comment: It's now a good use case for the Schwartzian Transform.

Comment: @zdim I want to share what I'm trying now but it's not working https://pastebin.com/uEvCFzcU if you can get it working please post as an answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort! Note -- to sort a collection you can't really iterate through it (unless you are _implementing_ a sorting procedure), but you'd rather send the whole thing to a `sort` function/library.  What you do there is more an attempt to implement a sort, and that's not easy.  A note: instead of `foreach (@ary) { my $elem = $_; ... }` you can do `foreach my $elem (@ary)`.  That's a nice provision that `foreach` gives us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort by the first three chars from each string, using an ancillary hash of month indices

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @data = ("Sep 8, 12, 15, 24", "May 3, 24, 25, 29", "Jan 23");

my @mons = qw(jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec);
my %mon_ind = map { $mons[$_] => $_+1 } 0..$#mons;

my @sorted_data = sort { by_mon(\%mon_ind, $a, $b) } @data;

say for @sorted_data;

sub by_mon {
    my $mi = shift;
    my ($m1, $m2) = map { lc(substr $_, 0, 3) } @_; 
    return $mi->{$m1} <=> $mi->{$m2};
}
```

prints

```
Jan 23
May 3, 24, 25, 29
Sep 8, 12, 15, 24
```

The code [posted on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/uEvCFzcU) effectively attempts to implement a sort.

Comment: Thank you! Much better than what I was trying.

Comment: Or `my %mon_ind;
    @mon_ind{@mons} = 1..12;`

Comment: `my %mon_ind; @mon_ind{@mons} = 1..12;` works for me but not `my %mon_ind = map { $mons[$_] => $_+1 } 0..$`.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride  Ah ... the `$#mons` is the index of the last element of the array `@mons`.  So `#mons` are a part of it, not a comment as it got shaded here :(  Sorry ... I'll try to clarify it somehow ... for starters, I removed the (unnecessary) comment following it